# Stack Overflow rejecting well-formatted code in question

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting, markdown

Stack Overflow is rejecting a post that I am trying to create regarding Python. It complains that my post has improper code formatting, for reasons that I don't understand, even though the preview mechanism parses it fine.

I have asked for help in the Python chat and was pointed toward a couple of meta posts which (unfortunately) *do not* solve the problem that I am experiencing.

I have attached a screenshot of the full webpage, which also shows the raw text of the original post.

Meta Posts:
[Heading, followed by code: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363421/heading-followed-by-code-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properl/363422#363422)
[This message keeps me from posting "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399893/this-message-keeps-me-from-posting-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-no)

Webpage Screenshot:

[image: Webpage Screenshot]

Comment: The chat discussion [starts here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50830021#50830021). This question doesn't make it clear what OP tried, so this might be useful. tl;dr: empty space before code blocks are already there; code fences don't seem to help; changing heading markdown doesn't seem to help.

Comment: That whole question is far too long

Comment: @charlietfl that's entirely beside the point of a false positive formatting warning. And I'd add that SWIG is used for interfacing C/C++ and in this case python. That usually means quite a few moving parts. If you take a closer look at the files detailed in the question, they are all minimal. The only long block of code is `setup.py` which is responsible for building the extension module, and as such is most relevant to answer the asker's problem (that has to do with building extension modules). So no, the question is not far too long.

Comment: Remove all irrelevant parts of the question. You don’t need a README (everything here will be licensed under CC BY SA). Don’t include “stubs” for irrelevant files. And I would remove the information about the file structure completely and if you need to convey that somehow (do you?) you can change the headers above your code blocks to have that info (eg `example.c` => `./swig_example/example.c`). It could be that the bulleted list is what’s causing the system to get tripped up.

Comment: @Laurel I can't believe it, but removing the bulleted list showing the file structure actually fixed it.  This is definitely a bug.

Comment: If you're on linux you can use the `tree` utility to draw yourself a nice ascii file tree instead.

Comment: @philipxy they can't post a question because of the false positive formatting warning. So there _is_ no version of the question yet. Or do you mean posting the raw markdown to some third-party site?

Comment: @AndrasDeak My mistake, of course there is no post. But then I would suggest that they put the problematic content as text at the end of this post.

Comment: Just strip everything out of that question. Check that if you tab out of the textbox the error will be gone. Add back the first paragraph, tab out of the textbox (to trigger a `validate-body` call), if no error, add the next paragraph. When you do get an error, remove the last sentence, tab out, check for the error. Rinse repeat for words, chars until you found the characters that trip the error condition. Report back here with your findings.

Comment: It also generally helps if you turn off caps lock when writing headers or any other text that has no reason to be in all-caps

Comment: At least for this meta question, couldn't an [MRE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) be much smaller (not a rhetorical question)?